# adsense click spamming

Tags: google-adsense, spam

### Questions

- What software do people use for adsense click spamming ?
- How are they structured ?
- How does it work ?
- How can we block them ?

I tried looking at google but not much information there already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdSense ads are displayed using Javascript and therefore I would suspect that most click fraud agents would manipulate existing browser software with a malicious plugin (or using macro software from the host operating system) to identify and trigger AdSense links.

As a site owner you can selectively serve ads (e.g. block ads for traffic from untrusted regions) but, unless your site is otherwise being adversely affected by unwanted traffic, you can ignore the issue and let Google identify click fraud and block fraudsters.

Google has much better tools and far greater resources than the average webmaster: your efforts will be better spent building legitimate traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Another tip I heard is that you don't serve any Google ads on your site, UNTIL you have enough traffic (few hundred a week/month) consistently for a while (months?). After building up the traffic, you can start serving the Google ads. If you do get hit with click spam, Google can look at this history of your site and determine that it's not YOU (the webmaster) that's doing it.

Doing the above will lessen the chance of your google adsense acct being cancelled.